# Large File Summation iin R or Python

Tags: python, r

I have a large data frame with 2 million records. The file contains individual customer records and variables.

```
CUST_ID = unique ID
FLAG_1 = 1, 0
FLAG_2 = 1, 0 
FLAG_2 = 1, 0  
SEGMENT = H, M
VISITS = numeric value
```

Here is an example head and tail:

```
      CUST_ID    FLAG_1    FLAG_2    FLAG_3    SEGMENT    VISITS
      1          0         0         0         M          18
      2          1         1         0         M          23
      3          1         0         1         H          19
      1999998    1         1         0         M          36
```

I can perform summary stats in R, but my colleague wants an output that will fit into excel so that he can build a pivot and run various scenarios on the data. For example, he wants to see counts by particular FLAG combinations and run sums based on FLAG and SEGMENT combination on visits.

My problem is that I can't figure out a solution on flattening the file to the unique combinations of FLAG and SEGMENT. I'm looking for an example in R, but would be interested in a solution in Python secondarily.

Desired output:

```
 Row   FLAG_1    FLAG_2    FLAG_3    SEGMENT    VISITS    CUST_ID
 1     0         0         0         H          sum       count
 2     0         0         1         H          sum       count
 3     0         1         1         H          sum       count
 4     0         1         1         H          sum       count
 5     1         0         0         H          sum       count
 6     1         0         1         H          sum       count
 7     1         1         0         H          sum       count
 8     1         1         1         H          sum       count
 9     0         0         0         M          sum       count
 10    0         0         1         M          sum       count
 11    0         1         1         M          sum       count
 12    0         1         1         M          sum       count
 13    1         0         0         M          sum       count
 14    1         0         1         M          sum       count
 15    1         1         0         M          sum       count
 16    1         1         1         M          sum       count
```

In essence, it would be every possible combination (2 x 2 x 2 x 2) and the corresponding sum of VISITS and count of CUST_IDs for that combo.

Here is the solution I came up with. Please let me know if anyone has a better one.

```
df_agg1 <- aggregate(CUST_ID ~ FLAG_1 + FLAG_2 + FLAG_3 + SEGMENT, data =   DF, length)
df_agg2 <- aggregate(VISITS ~ FLAG_1 + FLAG_2 + FLAG_3 + SEGMENT, data = DF, sum)

#bind CUST_ID to COUNT in VISIT data frame
df_agg2$COUNT <- df_agg1$CUST_ID
```

Comment: It kind of sounds like they just want to build a pivot table

Comment: So what is the desired output here?

Comment: The desired output is a smaller, collapsed data frame that I can export to excel. My business partner would then throw it into a pivot.

Comment: Dason, exactly. I need to get the file summarized down to a size that excel can handle. I would prefer to use R to do the manipulation.

Comment: I'm asking specifically for this sample input, what's the desired output? I don't understand how you want to collapse this data.

Answer (score 0):

- Bulid a new column with this formula: `=B5&C5&D5&E5`. From the first row of your data it would give `001M`.
- Select the cell with the formula and go up to the end of your data. You would get new data like `110M` for the 2. row, `101M` for the third and etc.
- Then you may use `=Frequency()` or a pivot table to count the unique values.

[Support.Office Frequency](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/count-unique-values-among-duplicates-8d9a69b3-b867-490e-82e0-a929fbc1e273)

---

Note - Excel's rows are up to `1048576`. However, if you are using Pivot, you may save the range as csv file and use it as a source for the pivot from "Use external data".